# .htaccess page redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have dynamically created image links coming to my index.html page. basically they look like:
http://catdeoderant.com/index.html?catpart=view&catimage=13

How do I use .htaccess to redirect these links to:
http://catdeoderant.com/stinkycats/gallery.php

I need it where when you click on an image the redirect happens. I also need the variables to be passed to the redirected page. The first variable will always be =view, but the second could be any number.

One more thing, since it's an index.html page, any link to index.html with no variables should not get redirected.

Thanks all, and I do love cats, but sometimes they do stink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^catpart=view&catimage=([0-9]+)$
  RewriteRule ^/index.html$  /stinkycats/gallery.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Edited on advice from LazyOne.

Expected result:

- index.html => index.html
- index.html?foo=bar => index.html
- index.html?catpart=view => index.html
- index.html?catpart=view&catimage=foobar => index.html
- index.html?catpart=view&catimage=13 => /stinkycats/gallery.php?catpart=view&catimage=13

I never used %{QUERY_STRING} before but it should be close to what you are trying to do according to this documentation http://fantomaster.com/faarticles/rewritingurls.txt

Comment: I'm sorry, but RewriteRule CANNOT match query string like that -- only path part only (e.g. `index.html`). To work with query string you have to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pattern-here` -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: @LazyOne Didn't knew that, I'll modify my answer. Thanks for the head-up.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the work Josh. It means alot. I've researched this plenty on my on, and your code looks good. The page just loops back to itself, and does not redirect. I do have a query string producing the dynamic image links, but still your code looks good. I'm wondering if some previous lines are needed in the code for .htaccess, or if some code needs put into .php.ini to let all this work. I'll work on it, any extra help would be great. Oh yeah, the query string looks like this, but only passes the two variables mentioned in this case.

Comment: 'GALLERY_VIEW_URL' => $this->url($this->get_params(array('catgal', 'catpart', 'cat_page', 'catmes', 'catss', 'cataction')) . 'catpart=view&catimage=' . $data['id']),

Comment: ^/index.html$ should be ^index.html$ and [R=301,L] should be [L] this works thanks from another post goes out to lazyone, thanks to JoshLeaves for the original code. This post is solved and closed.